# Получить список файлов, которые находятся на сервере

Tags: linux, консоль, ftp

Есть только FTP доступ. Как получить список всех файлов в директории на удаленном сервере?
Следующая команда не учитивает файлы в подпапках:

```
curl -l ftp://wordpr007.ftp.tools/wordpress-developer.org/www/wp-content/uploads/ --user wordpr007_ftp:3JHac82R2
```

Comment: [Здесь](https://askubuntu.com/questions/639525/how-to-get-a-recursive-ftp-directory-listing-without-write-permissions) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614319/recursive-ftp-directory-listing-in-shell-bash-with-a-single-session-using-curl), например.

Comment: `man lftp` наверное